# Error creating new content types when Uwsgi kills a worker

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, uwsgi

I am Running a django application with uwsgi, I am observing a case Sometimes, when uwsgi kills it's worker and and respawns a worker.

```
Thu Aug  8 11:02:33 2019 - worker 1 killed successfully (pid: 25499)
Thu Aug  8 11:02:33 2019 - Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 4192)
```

And then the next request received by the django application returns 500 error with Exception:

RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.

at line

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Coupon)
```

EDIT:

Django version: 1.8.6
Uwsgi Version: 2.0.12

Comment: Well like the error says before, you likely did not make migrations, or migraed the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This is working fine for all requests, but this error appears only after uwsgi kills worker and new worker is spawned. If it is due to migration, shouldn't this error appear for every request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ISSUE**

I went through multiple sources and Content Types code, I found the reason for this case.

The Error occurred on this line

`content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Coupon)`

here, get_for_model method first fetches the object from cache. If it fails, it gets from DB, else creates the record in DB.

In my case, the Connection to DB was disrupted leading to OperationalError and for this error it raises RuntimeError with the Error description mentioned in question.

The same Error can also be returned in case of IntegrityError or ProgrammingError.

**OperationalError**
    Exception raised for errors that are related to the database's operation and not necessarily under the control of the programmer, e.g. an unexpected disconnect occurs, the data source name is not found, a transaction could not be processed, a memory allocation error occurred during processing, etc. It must be a subclass of DatabaseError.

**IntegrityError**
    Exception raised when the relational integrity of the database is affected, e.g. a foreign key check fails. It must be a subclass of DatabaseError.

**ProgrammingError**
    Exception raised for programming errors, e.g. table not found or already exists, syntax error in the SQL statement, wrong number of parameters specified, etc. It must be a subclass of DatabaseError.

**Snippet from Django 1.8.6 Source-code:**

```
def get_for_model(self, model, for_concrete_model=True):
    """
    Returns the ContentType object for a given model, creating the
    ContentType if necessary. Lookups are cached so that subsequent lookups
    for the same model don't hit the database.
    """
    opts = self._get_opts(model, for_concrete_model)
    try:
        return self._get_from_cache(opts)
    except KeyError:
        pass

    # The ContentType entry was not found in the cache, therefore we
    # proceed to load or create it.
    try:
        try:
            # We start with get() and not get_or_create() in order to use
            # the db_for_read (see #20401).
            ct = self.get(app_label=opts.app_label, model=opts.model_name)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            # Not found in the database; we proceed to create it.  This time we
            # use get_or_create to take care of any race conditions.
            ct, created = self.get_or_create(
                app_label=opts.app_label,
                model=opts.model_name,
            )
    except (OperationalError, ProgrammingError, IntegrityError):
        # It's possible to migrate a single app before contenttypes,
        # as it's not a required initial dependency (it's contrib!)
        # Have a nice error for this.
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes "
            "is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually."
        )
    self._add_to_cache(self.db, ct)
    return ct
```

**SOLUTION**

I need to upgrade my Uwsgi to or above 2.0.14 as before this version, Uwsgi kills any old worker to only give resources to Cheap Workers.